# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3

Tags: repository, build.gradle, android-studio-3.2

I can't solve this problem, please help me! I've got the following error:

```
Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/invincible/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
    file:/C:/invincible/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar
    file:/C:/invincible/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
    file:/C:/invincible/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar
    file:/C:/invincible/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
    file:/C:/invincible/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar
    http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
    http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar
Required by:
    project :app

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager
```

I tried to download, but there shows this:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Could not find resource"
  } ]
}
```

and my `build.gradle` shows Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly.

my `build.gradle` code:

```
***android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        customDebugType {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.3"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'***
```

I'm sorry for my English and please help me

Comment: Can you help me

Comment: I have a same error.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Not yet. When I opened  my dir /extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/  - I found just 26.0.0-alpha1 version of appcompat-v7 .  I confused.

Comment: I have the same problem. How to be? I don' know.And the main problem is 28.0.3 .jar .pom can't be downloaded. And there is error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace this dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3'
```

with this

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

And also remove this line

```
 buildToolsVersion '28.0.3
```

this is work for me .

Answer (score 3):

You can check latest version of `appcompat-v7` there: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7?repo=google.
So, you can find just **`appcompat-v7:28.0.0`**.

You must change 
`appcompat-v7:28.0.3` to `appcompat-v7:28.0.0`. No more else.